# How to find IP address of OTHER WiFi Devices on network programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, networking, microcontroller, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 that connects to my WiFi network after being configured (via WiFi Manager library) and runs a HTTP web server that displays certain sensor data. It connects to my specific network with a 192.168.0.XX IP and it works well.

My problem comes with the android app, and how to actually programmatically retrieve the IP that the webserver is running on? My routers DHCP only reserves IP's for a week - so hardcoding the IP into the app is not a good option, and having less tech-savvy people find the IP and configure it themselves is also not what I'm looking to do.

I also can't hardcode a static IP as friends & family will be using this with different networks and routers (so 192.168.0.X would not work on a router with an IP of 10.0.0.1 for example).

So, how do I go about programmatically getting the IP of my ESP8266 that is connected to my local network?

Comment: That is why we have multicast. Have the server subscribe to a known multicast group, then you can send queries to that multicast group, and the server can respond via unicast with its information. The multicast group is independent of whatever network it is on or its addressing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that maybe isn't very optimal and professional, but will do for hobby project. You can make your android app scan your local network using http GET on all addresses - e.g. trying to GET something like this: http://192.168.0.X/sensor_status. You can configure your esp8266 device to respond with code 200 (OK) and save this address in your android app's persistent storage. Next time you can simply check if there is ip saved in persistent storage and try to connect to it. If esp8266 is not available under remembered ip, you can re-scan your network.